# How do I get rid of the small lines between cells in a table?

Tags: tables, pdftex, color, overleaf, multirow

I'm trying to make a table with the first column and row as colored, but the rest of the cells in white. Though it works almost as expected, there's a thin white line between some cells that should be merged I'd love to get help removing them.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{iopart}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
    \begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{5.25cm}p{5.25cm}}
        \rowcolor{black}
      &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\color{white}Title A}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}
      {\textbf{\color{white}Title B}} \\  
         
        \cellcolor{black}\textbf{\color{white}Foo A }
            &   X
            &   Y \\ \hhline{~--}   
        
        \cellcolor{black} & X & Y\\
        \cellcolor{black}& X& Y\\
        \multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor{black}\color{white}Foo B}& X& Y\\ \hhline{~--} 

        \cellcolor{black}\textbf{\color{white}Foo C} 
            &   X 
            &   Y\\
        \cellcolor{black}
         &  &   Y \\
        \cellcolor{black}
         &  &   Y \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption.}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image: A table with a thin white line between cells in the first column that are blank]

Foo A (Row 2) needs no changing.

Foo C (Rows 6-8) I want to get rid of the white spacing connecting the three rows.

Foo B (Rows 3-5) was my attempt at using a solution I found in this [similar question I thought might help by using multirows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543772/vertically-merged-cells-in-fancy-colored-table-with-vertical-text). Apart from not removing the white line between the cells, it also centers the "Foo B" text vertically, which I don't want.

Ideally, I would like the result to look like this (but with Foo B at the top of its rows):
[image: A table without a thin white line between cells in the first column that are blank]

Thanks!

Comment: the colortbl package explicitly documents that it is incompatible with `\cline`.  You could use `hhline` to draw the rules or use a more modern package such as `tabularray` which uses different mechanisms to colour the cells.

Comment: Sure, switched to hhline, the problem remains the same though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) makes better tables with clean code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {p{3cm}p{5.25cm}p{5.25cm}},
    row{1} = {bg=gray2,fg=white,c},
    column{1} = {bg=gray2,fg=white,font=\bfseries},
  }   
                           & Title A & Title B \\          
                     Foo A & X       & Y       \\\hline
    \SetCell[r=3]{h} Foo B & X       & Y       \\ 
                           & X       & Y       \\
                           & X       & Y       \\\hline
    \SetCell[r=3]{h} Foo C & X       & Y       \\
                           & X       & Y       \\
                           & X       & Y       \\\hline
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Inside `\SetCell` command, `r=3` is for mulitrow, and `h` is for vertical alignment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Any idea how to download tabularray? I've been trying to follow that link all day, but it keeps saying the server is down?

Comment: @EnigmaticBacon If you are using TeXLive 2021 or MikTeX 2021, you only need to update it to get latest `tabularray` package (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution).

Comment: @EnigmaticBacon If you are using an older TeX distribution, you can download these two files from their github repositories: https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/raw/main/tabularray.sty
https://github.com/lvjr/ninecolors/raw/main/ninecolors.sty

Comment: I'm using Overleaf. I'm not sure what version of TeX that is :)

Comment: @EnigmaticBacon Then you may download the above two files and put them into your project folder on Overleaf.

Comment: I now get Package Tabulararray Error: your LaTeX release is too old

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133860/discussion-between-enigmaticbacon-and-l-j-r).

Comment: @EnigmaticBacon You need to change texlive version to 2021 on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code with the classical package `colortbl` (loaded by the key `table` of the package `xcolor`) which gives a good output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{orange}

\begin{table*}

\sffamily

\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}w{l}{3cm}w{l}{5.25cm}w{l}{5.25cm}}
    \rowcolor{black}
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}Title A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}Title B} \\
    Foo A & X & Y \\ \cline{2-3}
    Foo B & X & Y \\
          & X & Y \\
          & X & Y \\ \cline{2-3}
    Foo C & X & Y \\
          &   & Y \\
          &   & Y \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption.}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

However, there are some thin white lines in the black panels (it depends of the PDF viewer: with `PDF.js`, used for instance by Firefox, they are usually present).

The package `nicematrix` has tools to address that problem.

Form the previous code, I will now:

- load `nicematrix` (and unload `colortbl`);
- replace `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}`;
- add the key `color-inside` (alias: `colortbl-like`) to say that there are instructions of color in the array itself (and not in so-called `\CodeBefore` provided by `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{orange}

\begin{table*}

\sffamily

\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}w{l}{3cm}w{l}{5.25cm}w{l}{5.25cm}}[color-inside]
    \rowcolor{black}
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}Title A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{white}Title B} \\
    Foo A & X & Y \\ \cline{2-3}
    Foo B & X & Y \\
          & X & Y \\
          & X & Y \\ \cline{2-3}
    Foo C & X & Y \\
          &   & Y \\
          &   & Y \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Caption.}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output (once again copied from Firefox).

[image: Output of the above]